# Delay processing of subscription to avoid DDP timeouts

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, meteor

I have multiple subscriptions in play which describe data, and per-user status of that data.  Ultimately this is displayed on a Google Map.

Let's call these:

- `shops` -- the list of shop id, name, and location.  This set uses the current map bounds as a limit to the data returned.
- `rating` -- a per-user scoring of this shop.  Currently, all ratings are returned, regardless of if the shop is in view or not.

Each of these subscriptions is currently running in its own `Tracker.autorun` block.  This works, but if the number of shops exceeds a given limit, Bad Things Happen.  The Bad Thing here is that DDP times out in some way, a re-sync begins, timeout, re-sync...  forever.

Please don't suggest that adding 20,000 markers to a Google Map is a bad idea.  I know this, but I want to do it anyway at this stage of development.

Bad Approach:

Initially, I created the markers inside a cursor observer for `shops` and would call a findOne() to look up if the shop had a rating or not.  This scales badly because MiniMongo does not have an index, and so became a linear search across the `rating` collection.

First Refine:

I later moved the adding of `shops` to the map as a second-phase.  If the subscription has become fully ready, I perform a find() and add the shops there.  This worked mostly.  It prevented DDP timeouts, but still takes a very long time to process the shop data with the internal findOne() call still being linear.

Second Refine:

I only subscribe to `shops` after all data for `ratings` has been loaded.  This is a minor change, but did actually improve performance slightly.  I suspect it is because previously, `shops` was loaded first, then as `ratings` was populated, markers had to be updated.  Preventing this double-update made things better.

Potential Third Refine:

This plan is to allow things to load in real-time with the added, changed, and removed callbacks for both collection cursors.  However, rather than doing a findOne() to check for a rating, I use the `ratings` callbacks to populate an object with shop IDs and if a marker exists, update it.  This object is then referenced by the shop add-marker and update-marker code.  E.g.:

```
@ratings = {}

recordRating: (id, rating) ->
   @ratings[id] = rating
   @updateMarker(id)
removeRating: (id) ->
   delete @ratings[id]
   @updateMarker(id)
```

This is a bit of work to refactor to do this.  Before I take the plunge, is there a better way?  Is there a Meteor package that will help solve this problem that I'm just not finding?

Comment: would you say you are attempting a "Reactive Join" ?  Iron Router can help manage waitOn dependencies.   Also, is it possible to store some minimal summary Rating information onto the Shop ?   Then the actual Rating full object can be retrieved upon some other interaction?

Comment: Yea, in effect, that is what I am doing.  I want all shops, but I also want user-specific flags on those shops.  In this case, I went with my option #3, for now.  I don't want the map to delay loading while all data is retrieved, and this allows me to scale up from 2k locations to around 50k.